# Unbinding, Destroying, or Removing previously declared jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, breakpoints, sticky

I'm using two scripts ([FixTo](https://github.com/bbarakaci/fixto) and [Breakpoints](https://github.com/Abban/jQuery-Breakpoints)) to allow for "sticky" elements on the page. The problem occurs when I resize the window. I need to destroy the FixTo functionality. Has anyone had any success with this:

```
$(window).bind('enterBreakpoint1024',function() {
  $('#log').text('debug: Entering 1024 breakpoint');
 // Sticky Elements (scroll)
 $('#stats').fixTo('.container');
 $('#extra').fixTo('.container', {mind: '#stats'});
 $('#right').fixTo('.container');
});

$(window).bind('exitBreakpoint1024',function() {
  $('#log').text('debug: Exiting 1024 breakpoint');
  // Need to Unbind, Destroy, or Remove the fixTo() function
});
```

Comment: `window.fixTo = null;` should remove any reference to that function.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I would assume if you remove the plugin reference like that, that any events bound by that plugin to any elements it was attached to are still there and will now crash as the plugin is gone. I think the plugin should provide a function to detach itself cleanly or you are going to have to know exactly what the plugin does and undo it yourself, as in: unbind any events, remove any elements the plugin might had added and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the plugin.

I added destroy, stop and start methods to the plugin. Now it is possible to stop functionality temporarily or permanently.

Fixto will not need breakpoint to work unless you are chasing a custom effect.